# 1D Array passed to worksheet offset by 1

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies as this is probably something really simple, but I can't work it out. I'm creating a 1d array (1 row by four columns) that I then pass to a worksheet. However the output is always offset by one position to the right. What I'm getting is this:

```
 Physics Lecturer   Pimp Status Number of Underlings    Total Backhands Delivered   
                    Robbo       Very High               15                        677
```

What I want is this:

```
   Physics Lecturer Pimp Status Number of Underlings    Total Backhands Delivered   
   Robbo            Very High   15                      677
```

My code is this:

```
    Sub Database_Appender()
    'Written by JDog's Underling on 01/04/2014.

        'Defining the sheet being work on and its number (in the order of sheets from first to last).
        Dim sht As Worksheet, sheet_number As Long

        'An array to contain all returned values (manufacturer, price, class, quotation date and region).

        no_of_entries = 4

        Dim Data_Array(4) As Variant

        sheet_number = 1
        Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_number)


        Data_Array(1) = sht.Cells(6, 2) 'Class
        Data_Array(2) = sht.Cells(6, 3) 'Region
        Data_Array(3) = sht.Cells(6, 4) 'Quotation Date
        Data_Array(4) = sht.Cells(6, 5) 'Comparable Price


        Sheets("Database").Range("A2").Resize(1, no_of_entries + 1) = Data_Array
    End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Simoco, thanks for your help but this shifts the array one more position to the right, whereas I won't it to go left. I tried changing the "1" to "-1" but vba doesn't like that. If possible I'd also like to understand why my array is offset in this way when export it, do you know why this is? Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are zero-based, so change your array declaration to this:

```
Dim Data_Array(3) As Variant
```

Then change you assignments to this:

```
Data_Array(0) = sht.Cells(6, 2) 'Class
Data_Array(1) = sht.Cells(6, 3) 'Region
Data_Array(2) = sht.Cells(6, 4) 'Quotation Date
Data_Array(3) = sht.Cells(6, 5) 'Comparable Price
```